# How to combine alternate lines in a file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, paste

I have a 4 line input file and i need to modify the file to combine alternate lines. I want to perform the operation in place.

```
INPUT:
Tom
Nathan
Jack
Polo

Desired Output:
Tom    Jack
Nathan Polo
```

One way is to collect odd numbered lines and flip them and cut even numbered lines and combine both files to get the final output. But i am looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given

```
$ cat INPUT
Tom
Nathan
Jack
Polo
```

then

```
$ pr -s -T -2 < INPUT
Tom     Jack
Nathan  Polo
```

(paginate with single tab spacing between columns, no headers, two columns); or

```
$ paste -d ' ' - - < INPUT | rs -T
Tom     Jack
Nathan  Polo
```

(paste then transpose)

Comment: What package provides the `rs` command?

Comment: @Wildcard on Ubuntu (so I guess other Debian-based systems) it has its own package called simply `rs` - my understanding is that it's originally a BSD utility so it may be packaged as such on other platforms?

Comment: Interesting.  Yes, it's pre-installed on Mac OS X (which uses BSD tools) but doesn't seem to exist at all for RHEL/CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below command to get the same.

I accept its complex one when compared to pr. But this is my try

```
for i in `sed -n '1~2p' l.txt`;do sed -n "/$i/,+1p" l.txt; done| split -l 2 |paste xaa xab
```

output

```
Tom     Jack
Nathan  Polo
```